# Can I pass a string list of attributes to an element and Astro will not have to further process it?

Tags: javascript, html, astrojs

If the title is a bit confusing, let me demonstrate it:

```
---
function elemAttrs(a, b, c) {
  return `data-a="${a}" data-b="${b}" data-c="${c}"`;
}
---
<div {elemAttrs('dog', 'cat', 'bird')}></div>
```

So basically I expect this output:

```
<div data-a="dog" data-b="cat" data-c="bird"></div>
```

But it outputs:

```
<div elemattrs('dog',="" 'cat',="" 'bird')="data-a=&quot;dog&quot; data-b=&quot;cat&quot; data-c=&quot;bird&quot;"></div>
```

Is there a way to do this in AstroJS?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by returning an object instead of a string from your function and then "spreading" the result using `...`:

```
---
function elemAttrs(a, b, c) {
  return {
    'data-a': a,
    'data-b': b,
    'data-c': c,
  };
}
---
<div {...elemAttrs('dog', 'cat', 'bird')}></div>
```